# IndexedDB NotFoundError

Tags: angular, typescript, indexeddb

I am working with IndexedDB trying to store an array. The array is being cached and I can see that in the dev tools but for some reason I am getting the following error: 
[image]

Here is the code that is causing the error:

```
    private async getExistingColumnsFromIndexDb() {
    let doesCacheExist: boolean;
    try {
        doesCacheExist = await this.indexedDbService.getKeyIsValid(SELECTED_COLUMNS_KEY, IndexedDBTableEnum.EMPTY_PLANNING_TASKS);
        if (doesCacheExist) {
            let cachedData: ISelectedColumns[];
            try {
                cachedData = await (this.indexedDbService.getCacheIfValid(SELECTED_COLUMNS_KEY, IndexedDBTableEnum.EMPTY_PLANNING_TASKS) as Promise<ISelectedColumns[]>);
                return cachedData;
            } catch (error) {
                // eventually log this to database - just conosole error for now and return empty array
                console.error('error getting column cache', `error: ${error}`);
                return [];
            }
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    } catch (error) {
        // eventually log this to database - just conosole error for now and return empty array
        console.error('error validating if cache exists', `error: ${error}`);
        return [];
    }
}

public async updateColumns(columns: any[]) {
    let existingColumns: ISelectedColumns[];
    try {
        existingColumns = await this.getExistingColumnsFromIndexDb();
    } catch (error) {
        // eventually log this to database - just conosole error for now
        console.error('failed retrieving existing columns tasks', `error: ${error}`);
    }
    return this.indexedDbService.putOnTable(
        [...columns.map(column => ({ columns: column} as ISelectedColumns)), ...existingColumns],
        CacheDurationEnum.NEVER,
        SELECTED_COLUMNS_KEY,
        IndexedDBTableEnum.EMPTY_PLANNING_TASKS
    );
}

public async getSelectedColumns() {
    return this.getExistingColumnsFromIndexDb();
}
```

The error does not show up if I do not included the `SELECTED_COLUMNS_KEY` in the updateColumns method. But, I am not getting data back since I am using the key in the method above.

Comment: In order to receive an answer to this question you need to provide more information about whatever indexedDbService is, because this error occurs within that module or in how you are using that module.